# Change background image on hover on Revolution Slider

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, background-image, slider-revolution

I would like to replicate the way background images change and start the zooming animation whenever the mouse hovers over the a particular element, [exactly like this](https://create.agency/agency).

Anyone with some expertise in CSS (and Revolution Slider API if needed) to make this work?

I tried setting up the layout and tried to add all the backgrounds needed as images resized to fit the entire area (to replicate the full screen behaviour), my thought behind this is to have all the images loaded as soon as the site loads, so the effect can be viewed instantly.

Thanks in advance!